# Code running in Dbeaver but not working when I implement the same via dbt

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbt

I am new to this thing and I have a doubt. I am migrating flows from tableau prep to dbt. There is this filter that is used in prep which goes like
`NOT ((([Tactic] == "Awareness") AND NOT (ISNULL([Tactic]))))`

and my corresponding code is like : `(tactic = 'Awareness' and tactic is not null) = false`,
tactic is a calculated field where we are deriving the values of tactic from other fields.

This code runs perfectly fine when I am using my sql editor(dbeaver) but does not give me proper values when I run it in DBT `Awareness` is included in the dbt output.

Here are the versions :

- DBT: 1.2.2
- postgres: 1.2.2
- redshift: 1.2.0

The packages cannot be upgraded as these will create issues in other flows that are being derived from my own flow.

has anyone else encountered a same issue or can someone please help me out with this?

I have tried doing `tactic <> 'Awareness'`.

Comment: This is temporarily fixed as I have done changes in the stage model, but the question still stands

Comment: Please share example data and your query to be able to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle bug here related to null handling that could be causing this.

For null values, `tactic = 'Awareness'` will be `null`, and `null and true` will also be `null`, which is not equal to `false`.

Generally, comparisons to booleans in Redshift [should use `is false`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_comparison_condition.html), not `= false`, and in this case, you really want `not ... is true`, not `is false`, since `not (null is true)` is true, but `null is false` is false.

I'd refactor this whole thing to something less dependent on the specifics of null handling for boolean operators for your database:

```sql
coalesce(tactic, '') <> 'Awareness'
```